# Update adapter data set from within another adapter

Tags: android

I have some adapters within a SeperatedListAdapter. I'm running into an `IllegalStateException` when I attempt to modify data for an adapter. The message is as follows:

> The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a
>   notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified
>   from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your
>   adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. [in
>   ListView(16908298, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class
>   com.mytest.ListTest.Adapter.SeparatedListAdapter)]

I was under the impression that the `notifyDataSetChanged` method only applies to adapters that have their data set changed, so I'm not sure why the exception is referencing SeperatedListAdapter. Below is my current code:

**ListFragment:**

```
public class FragmentOne extends ListFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
        SeparatedListAdapter sepList = new SeparatedListAdapter(getActivity());
        sepList.addSection("List One", new CustomAdapter(getActivity()));
        setListAdapter(sepList);
    }   
}
```

**CustomAdapter:**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final List<String> data;

    public CustomControllerAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        data = new ArrayList<String>(((MainActivity) context).getList());
    }       

    public void removeFromList(String name) {
        data.remove(name);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addToList(String name) {
        data.add(name);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }       
}
```

Could someone explain what I'm missing?

EDIT: After some more testing, I found that if I pause and resume the activity, the list does indeed update. I'm still not sure what I have to do to have it update while the activity is running, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what the issue was. In my situation, I wanted to add an additional TextView to my adapter without adding it to the list, so I added my desired amount to the existing list count. When `notifyDataSetChanged` is called, the item specified item is removed from the list, however the count size caused Type Casting exceptions. I've since removed this and everything is working as expected.